# Formatting string in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I'm doing a jQuery Ajax call to a PHP script that returns this string variable in Javascript:

```
"<div id=\"page\">\r\n\r\n\t"
```

I'm probably missing something simple here, but is there a way to revert `\r\n` to `<br/>`, but more importantly, reverting `\"page\"` to `"page"` ? I just can't figure it out.

Javascript looks like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "JSON",
        url:  sameURLasPHPscript,
        success:function(data){
            // successful request; do something with the data
            $('body').text(data);
        },
        error:function(){
            // failed request; give feedback to user
            alert('ErrorMessage');
        }
    });
```

My php file looks like this:

```
        $url = "someURL/controller/action/getID";

        $a = file_get_contents($url);           

        echo json_encode($a);
```

**Edit : Solution can be found here: http://blog.dkferguson.com/index.cfm/2011/3/15/jQuery-Mobile-styling-loaded-content**

Comment: What does your PHP code look like? You should probably fix it from there.

Comment: The fact of the matter is, some tweaking of the server-side script would be best, since it is producing this unhelpful output.

Comment: @David everything is as it should be, until I do json_encode($b). Is there a way to do this in PHP?

Comment: @SalmanA That's a leftover from testing. I will remove it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server is sending JSON encoded data, you should treat it likewise. Change the parameters of your jQuery.ajax so that it expects JSON data. jQuery will then parse the data and deal with all `\"`, `\r` and `\n`.

## Edit

Compare the output of these two jQuery functions:

```
$('body').text("<b>bold</b>"); // will write <b>bold</b> literally
$('body').html("<b>bold</b>"); // will write bold in bold font
```

You need to use [`jQuery.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function to display HTML as HTML.

Comment: I decided it would be best if I don't do json_encode(). Is there a way I can convert these characters in PHP instead of javascript?

Comment: Your answer had the same result as changing `json_encode($b)` to `echo $b` as I stated in my Question Edit.

Comment: Changing from .text() to .html() almost did the trick. Now firebug show the HTML-code being injected into the HTML page, but it is greyed out, and it doesn't show in browser yet either.

Comment: Not sure. By grayed out do you mean the element is displayed _dimmed_? Hidden elements or elements not injected in DOM appear dimmed.

Comment: I created a div to inject the HTML in, and now the HTML shows, but it doesn't have the styling a added to it, which it does have on other pages.

Comment: No, I added a div in my HTML and added the HTML like this `$('#newDiv').html(jsonData);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11187/discussion-between-salman-a-and-kristof-w)

Comment: I googled "jquery mobile page loses styling when loading ajax content" and ended up upon http://blog.dkferguson.com/index.cfm/2011/3/15/jQuery-Mobile-styling-loaded-content

Answer (score 3):

You can strip the slashes using this function:
http://phpjs.org/functions/stripslashes:537

And you can replace \r\n with this function:
http://phpjs.org/functions/nl2br:480

Comment: This is just a workaround, it won't solve the actual problem.